# Automatically reloading raster layers if source is changed in QGIS using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, layers

How to  automatically reloaded raster layer if source is changed? (The path is the same but inside source file are changes)

I use:

```
 qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas().refresh()
```

but layer not refresh.

#
#
#

The maps are repainting but there are still the same image (source file is changed on disc)

I use:

```
  layers = qgis.utils.iface.legendInterface().layers()
  for layer in layers:
      layer.triggerRepaint()
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I suppose your question does not include change detection, as your sample only concerns `QgsMapCanvas.refresh()`

Instead you have to call [`QgsRasterLayer.triggerRepaint()`](http://www.qgis.org/api/classQgsRasterLayer.html#ad2fabc4fdc3bce56d615b5513767eaa9)

If your layer is called myLayer:

```py
myLayer.setCacheImage( None )
myLayer.triggerRepaint()
```

The same method exists for vector layers as well.

For low overhead file change notification I'd propose looking into Qt's [`QFileSystemWatcher`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qfilesystemwatcher.html#details), which makes use of [inotify](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify) on linux and [similar techniques](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-ch/library/windows/desktop/aa364417%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on [other](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/FSEvents_ProgGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) [platforms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kqueue).

```py
from PyQt4.QtCore import QFileSystemWatcher

def refreshLayer():
    myLayer.setCacheImage( None )
    myLayer.triggerRepaint()

watcher = QFileSystemWatcher()
watcher.addPath( '/path/to/your/raster' )
watcher.fileChanged.connect( refreshLayer )
```

Of course this can be combined with an MD5 check as proposed by nickves or a  modification time check with `os.stat` (Nathan W proposal).

Answer (score 2):

You can check if the file hash has changed between intervals

eg:

```
def md5checksum(fp):
        import hash
    with open(fp, 'rb') as fh:
        m = hashlib.md5()
        while True:
            data = fh.read(8192)
            if not data:
                break
            m.update(data)
        return m.hexdigest()

import time
import copy

a,b = str(),str()
while True:
    a =  md5checksum(fp) # file
    if a != b:  # the file has changed, do what you want
        myLayer.triggerRepaint()
        b = copy.copy(a) #shallow copy, otherwise a and b will point at the same object
    else:
        sleep.time(1) #wait for 1 sec, then recheck
```

It's a bit hackish, but the underline idea is valid

(The md5 hash check found [here](http://www.joelverhagen.com/blog/2011/02/md5-hash-of-file-in-python/))

Answer (score 1):

The excellent answer from Matthias Kuhn is nearly 10 years old and can be adapted to more recent (as of 2023) QGIS by using Qt5 and a different newer reload method. It is also possible to automatically take the filename from the currently selected raster layer:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QFileSystemWatcher
rasterLayer = iface.activeLayer()
watcher = QFileSystemWatcher()
watcher.addPath(rasterLayer.dataProvider().dataSourceUri())
watcher.fileChanged.connect(rasterLayer.dataProvider().reloadData)
```

In my experience on QGIS 3.16.16 this filesystem watcher approach works well, with the QGIS display updating and providing immediate feedback as soon as my external application changes the file.

I was having no success with setCacheImage(None), triggerRepaint(), and other older suggestions. QGIS seemed to only present fragments of the new data together with cached fragments of the previous version.