# Updating data from external table in real time using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, real-time

I have been trying for a long time to connect a external table data[csv] through Excel (for exmaple) with QGis with the objective to each time i change any data in table(for example data location - coordinates [X ; Y]),this changes occur in QGis real time.

Is there any procedure to get it?.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Although the original question was aimed at raster layers, the same procedure can be applied here with simple python scripting. See https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/58885/9839

```
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import QFileSystemWatcher

def refreshLayer():
    myLayer.setCacheImage( None )
    myLayer.triggerRepaint()

watcher = QFileSystemWatcher()
watcher.addPath( '/path/to/your/csv' )
watcher.fileChanged.connect( refreshLayer )
```

Comment: Note this answer does not work for modern versions of QGIS.

Comment: Fixed, please check the update