# How to access layer in QGIS?

Tags: qgis

I want to get QGIS to update from a CSV file like in this [How to update data from external table in real time?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/64722/how-to-update-data-from-external-table-in-real-time) question, however I can't figure out what to put for "myLayer". How can I define the active QGIS layer in my code?

Answer (score 1):

The most basic approach would be

```
myLayer = iface.activeLayer()
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! However I did try that and I got 'name "iface" is undefined' so it doesn't compile - do you know why?

Comment: Which QGIS version are you using? The code provided by @underdark should work (I use QGIS 2.2 and 2.6 and worked for both). To be extra safe, you could first try `import qgis.utils` and then `myLayer = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()`

Comment: I'm using 2.6 and import qgis.utils worked! Thank you so much.