# QgsMapCanvas.refresh() does not reload new wfs layer features, but panning does

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I have a wfs layer loaded in a standalone QGIS app, which I am updating by running a database query on the view it is based on. The feature is added with no problems and I reload the layer with:

```
# Runs insert query here to add feature to WFS layer source table
wfs_vector_layer.dataProvider().updateExtents()
wfs_vector_layer.dataProvider().reloadData()
main_window.mapCanvas().refresh()
```

However, the `refresh()` does not visibly update the canvas, and I have to pan or zoom the canvas to get it to redraw the updated wfs layer with the new feature. I can't see anything more than a `refresh()` happening after panning from the [qgsmaptoolpan](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/src/gui/qgsmaptoolpan.cpp#L59) source code. Am I using the method incorrectly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved it with:

```
wfs_vector_layer.triggerRepaint()
```

From this answer: [How to automatically reload raster layers if source is changed in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/58814/how-to-automatically-reloaded-raster-layer-if-source-is-changed-in-qgis?rq=1)