# QGIS gets stuck when running script to automatically refresh layer

Tags: pyqgis

I have a QGIS layer that represents a set of links and nodes to show the streets of a city and the traffic speeds on each street. I've been trying to write a script so that if I change the speeds in the CSV file (links3.csv) the speeds will automatically update in QGIS. However when I run the code I currently have, then change the file, the entire program freezes and I have to force quit it.

```
import qgis.utils
from PyQt4.QtCore import QFileSystemWatcher

myLayer = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()
def refreshLayer():
    myLayer.setCacheImage( None )
    myLayer.triggerRepaint()

watcher = QFileSystemWatcher()
watcher.addPath( '/Users/username/Traffic Speeds/links3.csv' )
watcher.fileChanged.connect( refreshLayer )
```

What am I doing wrong? I got the code to automatically refresh the layer from [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/58814/how-to-automatically-reloaded-raster-layer-if-source-is-changed-in-qgis/58885#58885)

Comment: Can you confirm that watcher* is eyeing the proper file?  I experienced a similar issue, part of the problem was an incomplete filepath.

Comment: I just tried re-writing the path and now it works! I think I had an extra space or something. Thank you so much!

Comment: Nice work!  You might add an answer to your question so as to help other future users out.

Answer (score 1):

Double check the filepath. In this case, there might be a small mistake in the filepath that causes the script to stop working.