# Refreshing QGIS view

Tags: python, pyqgis, qgis-2, rendering

I've written a short python script for use in QGIS (currently using 2.8.1) to set the CRS for all loaded layers to OSGB 1936 / BNG. The script correctly sets the CRS but I have to manually scroll in/out to refresh the screen after running it - not a big issue though slightly annoying and possibly easy to fix!

I've tried using the code snippet below to refresh but I still have to manually scroll in/out.

```
qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas().refresh()
```

Is there a line of code to force a full refresh/re-render of all loaded data?

Comment: Does this question help? http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/58814/43

Comment: Yep thanks! I knew there'd be a simple answer but I couldn't see it anywhere. Put that as an answer and I'll accept.